# Fgets while loop, compiler warning about a statement with no effect

Tags: c, gcc, fgets

What can I do to get rid of the compiler warning about a statement with no effect?
I'm using fgets to read the output of a bash command, but I don't need to or want to do anything with it apart from outputting it to my buffer.

```
while (fgets(pid, sizeof(pid), fp) != NULL) {
    1; //Statement with no effect :(
}
```

Comment: Remove the statement; an empty block is acceptable. But also, why are you even using a loop?

Comment: You're right I probably don't even need to since the output of this particular bash command could only contain a newline at the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have the `1;` line? You can have empty `while` loops

```
while (fgets(pid, sizeof(pid), fp) != NULL) {
}
```

Or

```
while (fgets(pid, sizeof(pid), fp) != NULL); // Note semi-colon
```

It's probably best to avoid the second option as it's easier to misunderstand what's going on.

Comment: Sometimes people add a comment: `while (...) /* do nothing */ ;`

Comment: Thanks guys! I like all three options :)